# ¿se puede enviar un correo a outlook con php utilizando APIs de google developer?

Tags: php, html, api, webservice, google-developers-console

Tengo este codigo en html el cual es un formulario con campos que se tendran que llenar

```
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="correo" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="correo" class="form-control" id="correo" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Nombre" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" name="" id="Nombre">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3 ">
    <label for="Asunto" class="form-label">Asunto</label>
        <input type="text" name="asunto" class="form-control" id="Asunto">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3 ">
    <label for="Mensaje" class="form-label">Mensaje</label>
        <input type="text" name="mensaje" class="form-control" id="Mensaje">
    </div>
    <?php
        include('procesar_datos.php');
    ?>

    <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

lo que quiero saber es que sin en el archivo "procesar_datos.php" puedo poner alguna API de google developer para enviar un correo con los datos que se pongan en los campos y de ser así ¿cómo haría eso?

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías explicar por qué necesitas una API de Google Developer para hacer esto? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta. No veo qué relación tiene esto con el entorno de Google, cuando hablas de Outlook en el título de la pregunta.